# sub query - list those that have the most

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I am trying to list the instructor of the Java courses that have been taught by the Instructor which has taught the most Java courses.

first I select Instructors that teach java courses

```
SELECT z.FIRST_NAME,z.LAST_NAME,b.COURSE_NO, MAX(b.DESCRIPTION) AS DESCRIPTION
FROM INSTRUCTOR z
JOIN SECTION w ON z.INSTRUCTOR_ID = w.INSTRUCTOR_ID
JOIN COURSE b ON w.COURSE_NO = b.COURSE_NO
WHERE DESCRIPTION like '%Java%'
GROUP BY z.FIRST_NAME,z.LAST_NAME,b.COURSE_NO
```

it displays results what I want so far

```
FIRST_NAME                LAST_NAME                  COURSE_NO DESCRIPTION                                      
 ------------------------- ------------------------- ---------- ---------------------------------
Tom                       Wojick                           120 Intro to Java Programming                          
Gary                      Pertez                           120 Intro to Java Programming                          
Anita                     Morris                           124 Advanced Java Programming                          
Todd                      Smythe                           122 Intermediate Java Programming                      
Charles                   Lowry                            122 Intermediate Java Programming                      
Charles                   Lowry                            120 Intro to Java Programming                          
Fernand                   Hanks                            122 Intermediate Java Programming                      
etc...
```

but when I try to select the instructors which has taught the most Java courses I get totally different result

```
SELECT z.FIRST_NAME,z.LAST_NAME,b.COURSE_NO,b.DESCRIPTION
FROM INSTRUCTOR z
JOIN SECTION w ON z.INSTRUCTOR_ID = w.INSTRUCTOR_ID
JOIN COURSE b ON w.COURSE_NO = b.COURSE_NO
WHERE DESCRIPTION like '%Java%'
GROUP BY z.FIRST_NAME,z.LAST_NAME,b.COURSE_NO,b.DESCRIPTION
HAVING MAX(b.DESCRIPTION) =
(SELECT MAX(DESCRIPTION) 
FROM (
SELECT z.FIRST_NAME,z.LAST_NAME,b.COURSE_NO, MAX(b.DESCRIPTION) AS DESCRIPTION
FROM INSTRUCTOR z
JOIN SECTION w ON z.INSTRUCTOR_ID = w.INSTRUCTOR_ID
JOIN COURSE b ON w.COURSE_NO = b.COURSE_NO
WHERE DESCRIPTION like '%Java%'
GROUP BY z.FIRST_NAME,z.LAST_NAME,b.COURSE_NO
 )
 )
ORDER BY z.FIRST_NAME,z.LAST_NAME,b.COURSE_NO,b.DESCRIPTION;
```

How could I count these description java courses and select max from it so it can only show one instructor with all his Java courses ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
WITH q AS (
SELECT z.FIRST_NAME,z.LAST_NAME,b.COURSE_NO, MAX(b.DESCRIPTION) AS DESCRIPTION
     , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY z.FIRST_NAME, z.LAST_NAME) TheCount
  FROM INSTRUCTOR z
       JOIN SECTION w ON z.INSTRUCTOR_ID = w.INSTRUCTOR_ID
       JOIN COURSE b ON w.COURSE_NO = b.COURSE_NO
 WHERE UPPER(DESCRIPTION) like '%JAVA%'
 GROUP BY z.FIRST_NAME,z.LAST_NAME,b.COURSE_NO
)
SELECT first_name, last_name, course_no, description
  FROM q
 WHERE TheCount = (SELECT MAX(TheCount) FROM q);
```

Note this may give you more than one instructor.

Also, I've compared the course description search string using all upper case to eliminate the possibility of missing a course because of JAVA being in a different case.

EDIT:

There are a number of SQL functions that can be used as "Analytic" functions - where the function is applied to the records that fall within a "window", i.e., the PARTITION BY clause. Some of them are sensitive to ordering as well, and an ORDER BY clause can be used as well.  You can find some good reference material [here at Tim Hall's site](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/analytic-functions.php). Another is at [Shouvik Basu's blog](http://www.orafaq.com/node/55).

Comment: I did get only one instructor which is perfect. I haven't learned "partition by" yet, but after looking it now, I will definitely use it in future. I also did not about "upper". Something to think about. Thank you very much.